Why MUI colors are set on transparency instead of different shades with 100% opacity?
I was wondering why Material UI colours in Figma Local Variables are set on transparency. For example primary/hover is basically 12% of primary/main, instead of choosing lighter shade of this colour with 100% opacity. Also text colour styles and component styles are build based on transparency.
Is there any reason for setting this colours on transparency? Isn't it better to just pick lighter shade without changing the opacity of the colour?
I read the MUI documentation, but couldn't find any particular reason why transparency would be better, than setting the specific shade of colour.
I would really appreciate any explanation in the subject!
